# Do polynomial bounds on a function imply polynomial bounds on absolute value of the function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, computational-complexity

Suppose I know that $f\in\mathcal{C}^{k}(\mathbb{R})$ is such that there exist monic polynomials $P_{1}$, $P_{2}$ of order $k$, that bound $f$:

\begin{align*} \forall x\in\mathbb{R}, \  C_{1}P_{1}(x)\le f(x)\le C_{2}P_{2}(x)\end{align*}for some constants $C_{1}, C_{2}>0$.  Can we then say for some perhaps different polynomials $\tilde{P}_{1}$, $\tilde{P}_{2}$, also of degree $k$, that

\begin{align*} \forall x \in\mathbb{R}, \ C_{1}|\tilde{P}_{1}(x)|\le |f(x)|\le C_{2}|\tilde{P}_{2}(x)|?\end{align*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let $f(x)=x+2\pi \sin x$ and $k=1$. Then the first condition holds with $P_1(x)=x-2\pi$, $C_1=1$, $P_2(x)=x+2\pi$, $C_2=1$. Assume there are $\tilde P_1$, and/or $\tilde P_2$ as requested.

We have $f(\pi)=\pi>0$, $f(\frac32\pi)=-\frac\pi2<0$, hence $f(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0\in(\pi,\frac32\pi)$. By symmetry, also $f(-x_0)=0$. Then 
$0\le C_1|\tilde P_1(\pm x_0)|\le |f(\pm x_0)=0$ implies that $\tilde P_1$ has two roots, contradicting $\deg \tilde P_1=k=1$. Hence no suitable $\tilde P_1$ exists.

Assume $\tilde P_2=x+b$ (you didn't specify explcitly that $\tilde P_2$ should be *monic* like $P_1, P_2$, but without that restriction the inclusion of $C_2$ in the inequality makes no sense). Then $-b$ msut be a zero of $f$. At that zero, $f'(-b)=1\pm 2\pi$, so $|f(-b+h)|\approx (2\pi-1)|h|$ for small $h$ whereas $C_2|\tilde P_2(-b+h)|=|h|$. For small $h$ this is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks!  This is helpful.  This approach was an attempt to address the following problem:  suppose $f\in\mathcal{C}^{k}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies $0<\epsilon<f^{(k)}(x)<\epsilon^{-1}$ for some $\epsilon$.  Can we conclude that $\epsilon|P_{1}(x)|<|f(x)|<\epsilon^{-1}|P_{2}(x)|$ for some $P_{1}, P_{2}$ monic polynomials of degree $k$ or less?  Taylor's theorem provides polynomial estimates above and below, but without the absolute values.  I had hoped the Taylor estimates would imply the ones I desire, but your counterexample shows that is not possible.

Comment: @JamesMurphy Ah, your original statement is about degree $k$ or *less*. And the leading terms are from bounds of $f^{(k)}$ (which would be $2pi+1$ in my example). That gives us a good sart for the right hand side, I guess. But since $f$ may have zeroes, the left habd sinde is of course impossible to arrange for.

Comment: It's interesting that you say the LHS is impossible.  In the case that $f$ has $k$ zeroes, the maximal number allowed under the regularity condition, we can actually realize the lower polynomial bound.  It's the intermediate case of fewer than $k$ roots that causes me headaches.  See my post on MO http://mathoverflow.net/questions/154783/improving-a-bound-from-taylors-theorem

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. If $f$ is bounded from above by some polynomial, then it is bounded also by $x^n+c$ for large enough $n, c$.